# Sql query with selected and splited column value from another table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables

First table

```
Id Type Value
1   2   1,2,3,5
2   1   1,3,6
3   1   2,3,1,6
```

Second table

```
Id Name
1  Leon
2  Anna
3  Biorn
4  Alex
5  Peter
6  Luis
```

Values in First table are Ids in Second table.

I need query that returns all names by type from the first table

For example:

```
Type = 1
return: Leon,Anna,Biorn,Luis
type = 2
return: Leon,Anna,Biorn,Peter
```

I'm trying to create a View that will look like this:

```
Type Name
1    Leon
1    Anna
1    Biorn
1    Luis
2    Leon
2    Anna
2    Biorn
2    Peter
```

So I can easily select all the names by type, but I can't figure out how to do it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to recognize that this is a poor data structure.  You should have a junction table -- storing lists of integers as a delimited string is not a SQLish data structure.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  Here is one thing you can do:

```
select t1.type, t2.name
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on ',' + t1.value + ',' like ',%' + cast(t2.id as varchar(255)) + '%,';
```